# How to make fixed scroll stick only till a certain section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer?
A good example I found was here : https://jumia.co.ke

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="scroll-to-top">Scroll Up</a>
```

CSS

```
.show-scroll-btn {
   position: fixed;
   transition: 350ms ease-in;
   bottom: 20px;
   z-index: 999;
```

}

JS

```
  const scrollToTop = document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top');

// Add event listener to make button appear when scrolling down
const showBtn = window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 300) {
        scrollToTop.classList.add('show-scroll-btn');
    } else {
    scrollToTop.classList.remove('show-scroll-btn');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was good, the only thing that wasn't working is that you had the condition `window.scrollY > 300`, meaning the program only gave the class `show-scroll-btn` after the user has scrolled 300px down. All that was needed to be changed is the condition to `window.scrollY < 300` as now the element has the class as long as the site's scrollY is below 300, and when it gets over 300, its being removed.

```js
const scrollToTop = document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top');

// Add event listener to make button appear when scrolling down
const showBtn = window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY < 300) {
        scrollToTop.classList.add('show-scroll-btn');
    } else {
    scrollToTop.classList.remove('show-scroll-btn');
    }
});
```

```css
.show-scroll-btn {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   transition: 350ms ease-in;
   z-index: 999;
```

```html
<a href="#" class="scroll-to-top">Scroll Up</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: You misunderstand me, I want to show the button after 300px all the way and then I want it to stick at a certain position (just before the footer) after fully scrolling down. I have given an example of a website that uses this concept

Comment: The button in the down right

Comment: Ok so I sorta fixed the problem, your answer worked, I made the mistake of not wrapping it in a div and adding the class onto the div instead of the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position: sticky` CSS property.

[Here's a guide on how to use it](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

Comment: I know about sticky and did try it, however it doesn't help. It just sticks there without going along with the page

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS

```
.scroll-to-top {
       position: sticky;
       transition: 350ms ease-in;
       top:calc(100% - 60px);
       z-index: 999;
       background:#fff;
       padding:5px; 
       right:20px;
       }
```

```css
.scroll-to-top {
   position: sticky;
   transition: 350ms ease-in;
   top:calc(100% - 60px);
   z-index: 999;
   background:#fff;
   padding:5px; 
   right:20px;
   }
```

```html
<p>
<a href="#" class="scroll-to-top">Scroll Up</a>
I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :</p>
<div>
stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed position makes it go all the way to the footer. Is there a way I can make it stop just before the footer? A good example I found was here :I made a fixed scroll to top button, once you scroll 300px it shows itself. I wanted to go further and make the button only stick till a certain se further and make the button only stick till a certain section as a fixed found was here :
</div>
```